# Parse and find string in between (English string inside double square bracket) with C#?

Tags: c#, regex, find

Below is code snippet. Wanted to find Item starts with "[[" and ends with "]]" and followed by any English letters a-z and A-Z. What is the efficient way?

```
 string sample_input = "'''அர்காங்கெல்சுக் [[sam]] மாகாணம்''' (''Arkhangelsk Oblast'', {{lang-ru|Арха́нгельская о́бласть}}, ''அர்காங்கெல்சுக்யா ஓபிலாஸ்து'') என்பது  [[உருசியா]]வின் [[I am sam]] [[உருசியாவின் கூட்டாட்சி அமைப்புகள்|நடுவண் அலகு]] ஆகும். <ref>{{cite news|author=Goldman, Francisco|date=5 April 2012|title=Camilla Vallejo, the World's Most Glamorous Revolutionary|newspaper=[[The New York Times Magazine]]| url=http://www.nytimes.com/2012/04/08/magazine/camila-vallejo-the-worlds-most-glamorous-revolutionary.html|accessdate=5 April 2013}}</ref>";          
List<string> found = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in sample_input.Split(' '))
{
  if (item.StartsWith("[[s") || item.StartsWith("[[S") || item.StartsWith("[[a") || item.StartsWith("[[a"))
  {                    
      found.Add(item);
  }
}
```

Expected Results: *[[Sam]]*, *[[I am Sam]]*, *[[The New York Times Magazine]]*.

Comment: Do you mean you only want to get `[[sam]]`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, now it will work for sam, since I added, similarly I wanted to get all the English words.

Comment: Like [this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%5c%5b%5ba-zA-Z%5d%2b%5d%5d&i=+%5b%5bsam%5d%5d+%e0%ae%ae%e0%ae%be%e0%ae%95%e0%ae%be%e0%ae%a3%e0%ae%ae%e0%af%8d%27%27%27++%5b%5b%e0%ae%89%e0%ae%b0%e0%af%81%e0%ae%9a%e0%ae%bf%e0%ae%af%e0%ae%be%5d%5d)?

Comment: tym32167 posted my suggestion already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
string sample_input = "'''அர்காங்கெல்சுக் [[sam]] மாகாணம்''' (''Arkhangelsk Oblast'', {{lang-ru|Арха́нгельская о́бласть}}, ''அர்காங்கெல்சுக்யா ஓபிலாஸ்து'') என்பது  [[உருசியா]]வின் [[உருசியாவின் கூட்டாட்சி அமைப்புகள்|நடுவண் அலகு]] ஆகும்.";
var regex= new Regex(@"\[\[[a-zA-Z]+\]\]");
var found = regex.Matches(sample_input).OfType<Match>().Select(x=>x.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: How to use the query, if the word is split. Example: [[I am Sam]]

Comment: @DineshkumarPonnusamy using this regex ```var regex = new Regex(@"\[\[[a-zA-Z ]+\]\]");```

Comment: Am not able to use the above expressions if the input is like [[I am so (sad)]], [[Are you Okay|Okay]], [[india.com]]. It's getting complex. can you help me? Thanks.